# Правильно ли я делаю? Создаю для каждого типа сообщения свой Сервис с своей бизнес логикой

Tags: javascript, node.js, ооп, solid

До обновления у меня был class MessageService, который принимал параметром userId, title, message и решал куда отправить сообщение.

```js
class MessageService {
  static async sendMessage(userId, title = '', message) {
    const typeId = await UserMessage.findTypeId(userId); // Достаем тип куда будем отправлять сообщение

    switch (typeId) {
      case 1:
        {
          // Email
          const email = '123@email.com';
          const result = await EmailService.sendMessage(email, title, message);
          return result;
        };
      case 2:
        {
          // Telegram Bot
          const telegramId = 123;
          const result = await TelegramService.sendMessage(telegramId, message);
          return result;
        };
      default:
        throw Error('Неизвестный тип');
    }
  }
}
```

Теперь в проекте появились html шаблоны для email и текстовые шаблоны для telegram они отличаются.
Теперь я думаю как это мне абстрагировать. Пока я придумал, для каждого типа сообщения, а именно:

1. При изменений пароля;
2. Уведомление о входе;
    и т д
   Создавать отдельный сервис например: MessageAuthService, который будет доставать свой шаблон и отправлять сообщение. 
   Такой вариант вполне адекватный или есть более разумное решение?

Comment: заведи класс на сообщение, которое знает где взять свой шаблон и с помощью какого сервиса себя отправить

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, разницы нет, как вы делаете, так как JavaScript не подразумевает выжимание из железа максимальной производительности в контексте Вашего примера и предполагаемых задач. Указанный формат, с использованием switch/case, очень удобен для меня, и не важно, используете Вы переход к функциям, или пишите её текст в рамках case. Размер кода всё равно остаётся неизменным, хотя, при вызове функций, добавляются расходы на передачу параметров и работу со стеком. Пишите так, как Вам удобнее понимать код.